# Differential inequality involving the Laplacian

Tags: calculus, inequality, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I have a differential inequality of the kind:
$$
\Delta f \ge f_x (1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2)
$$
where $f \colon \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Assume to know that $f_x > 0$ on $\Omega$ and $f$ is convex, so in particular $f_{xx} \ge 0$ and $f_{yy} \ge 0$.

From this I would like to show that $\Omega$ can not be the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$. I tried to show one of the partial derivatives must blow up in a bounded region, but all the ideas I tried didn't work.

Any hint would be really appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove the $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^1$ case, and give you a hint about the $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$ case: apply the scaling $y\mapsto y/k$ for $k\gg 1$ to make the $f_{yy}$ derivative small.  If you would like more details, I can provide a complete solution.

Let us consider the simpler case of $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ solving $f_{xx}\ge f_x(1+f_x^2)$, assuming similar conditions on $f$.  We have $\frac{1}{f_x(1+f_x^2)}=\frac{1}{f_x}-\frac{f_x}{1+f_x^2}$, so after rearranging, the inequality becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\frac{f_x}{\sqrt{1+f_x^2}}\ge 1.
$$
Let $g(x)=e^{-x}\frac{f_x}{\sqrt{1+f_x^2}}$.  Then integrating the inequality implies $g(x)\ge g(0)$.  But $g(x)\le e^{-x}$, so $g(0)=0$, a contradiction to $f_x>0$.

**EDIT:** The above hint was wrong! (The rescaling is supposed to be in *all* variables, not just $y$)  I have included (what I believe is) the correct solution below, but if this also has errors, please unaccept my answer.

First, let $f$ be such a solution of the inequality.  For each $k>1$, the rescaled function $f_k(x,y)=k f(k^{-1}x,k^{-1}x)$ is also a solution, and it has the same positivity properties.  We will derive an inequality valid for all solutions $g$, then substitute $g=f_k$ and re-express in terms of $f$.

For simplicity, let us remove the $g_y^2$ term:
$$
g_{xx}+g_{yy}\ge g_x(1+g_x^2),
$$
such that
$$
\partial_x\ln\frac{g_x}{\sqrt{1+g_x^2}}\ge 1-\frac{g_{yy}}{g_x(1+g_x^2)}.
$$
Hence, 
$$
e^{-x}F[g](x,y)\ge F[g](0,y)G[g](x,y),
$$
where
\begin{align}
F[g](x,y)&:=\frac{g_x(x,y)}{\sqrt{1+g_x^2(x,y)}},\\
G[g](x,y)&:=\exp-\int_0^x\frac{g_{yy}(t,y)}{g_t(t,y)(1+g_t^2(t,y)}dt.
\end{align}
Let us now put $g=f_k$.  Observe that
\begin{align}
F[f_k](x,y)&=F[f](k^{-1}x,k^{-1}y),\\
G[f_k](x,y)&=G[f](k^{-1}x,k^{-1}y).
\end{align}
This means
$$
e^{-kx}F[f](x,y)\ge F[f](0,y)G[f](x,y).
$$
Fixing $x>0$ and letting $k\to \infty$ gives the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This hint is extremely useful. I actually have managed the 1-dimensional case, but I don't know why I haven't thought about that scaling trick! I'll work out the details and if I get stuck I'll ask you again. Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: I am not sure anymore about the rescaling trick. We want to make $f_{yy}$ small in order to apply the $1$-dimensional argument, but how can we be sure that the rescaled function is still a solution of the differential inequality?

Comment: @Onil90 Indeed, the rescaled function will solve a different inequality, but its value at $y=0$ solves the same one except with small $y$ derivatives.  I'll append my answer with a more complete version of my thoughts later today.

Comment: @Onil90 See the edit.  If this also has errors, please unaccept my answer and accept my apologies!